# Edit Box not showing up on Windows 7

Tags: wix, controls, edit, wix3.5

I have downloaded the newest version of Wix Toolset and have made a custom dialog to get the connection string for the database from the user. When I test run the Msi on a Windows 7 machine, the dialog box is there as well as my display text, but the edit control is not showing up. If I click on where it is supposed to be, I get a cursor and if I start typing then the white background on the textbox shows up. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you show the code for your dialog? And does it show up on previous Windows versions as expected?

Comment: Please check that the other controls are not overriding edit box. Reduce the size of text box and then test

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly this is a Z-order problem where another control is overlapping with the control you want. First, ensure your controls don't overlap. Then, order them in the `Dialog` element such that the highest z-order are last (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the edit boxes were "invisible" until I clicked on them.  After examining the code, I realized that my controls were being "painted over" by my dialog bitmap.  I made the bitmap code the first line in the dialog and this fixed the problem as the controls got "painted over" the bitmap.